# Unable to build React Native 0.61.1 via CocoaPods

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, react-native-ios

Exact Error:

[image]

Podfile:

[image]

Linked Frameworks:

[image]

Already tried:

1)deleting npm modules

2)deleting pods folder

Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need put many thing into Linked Frameworks like that. In RN version > 0.6 just cd ios and pod install . That's the way it's work .
In Exact Error you can see ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 . Check this issue and fix it

Comment: Thanks for responding Zem Zem. 
1)As you said, I have trimmed down the number of Linked frameworks and kept only internal ones(that are not related to ReactNative).
2)  ReactNative has been added to this project via CocoaPods and is not created via "react-native init ". I Can't seem to find any "ios" directory here as you mentioned. 
Could you please elaborate on "cd ios" part?

Comment: So sorry i never tried add RN to any project via CocoaPods .I just created new project and always have android and ios folder

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is because you have React Native added via CocoaPods and some 3rd party library added as a "Linked Framework". And that library is looking for "RCTRootView" as if it was added the same way too.

Few questions:

- Are you building an iOS app or some framework? I see the error is from a `.framework` file, but we're talking about the iOS app. Please check if you have a proper target selected next to the device in the top left corner of XCode.
- Can you paste or link to a screenshot of a file / exact line that triggers the error? Should be `#import ...`

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for responding. 
Please check this screenshot of list of Linked Framworks. I have trimmed it down only a few essential ones. https://imgur.com/aNsOFIf

I just ran a quick search in my project and found that there are no "RCTRootView" imports in them.

1) Am building an app and this is just an Xcodeproj I have extracted out so that it could build the project quicker. I get the same error when I run the app too. And yes, verified that target selected is correct.

2)  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmtd5.jpg : Xcode isn't pointing to any specific import statements

Comment: Previously the error was at this import statement
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h> 

I just changed this to:
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

And this import problem got fixed but ended up landing in this state:

 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmtd5.jpg